# Migrating from IdentityServer 2.4.0 -> IdentityServer4 4.1.2

Tags: migration, identityserver4, identityserver2

We are getting ready to do an upgrade to our IdentityServer from v2.4.0 to the latest 4.1.2 and thought we'd throw it out there for input from others that have had to accomplish this.

I have found some good reading on migrating from 3.1.x to 4.1.2 but nothing for our current version of 2.4.0.

Any information others can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So the practical thing to do, especially with opensource technology is to follow the natural upgrade path. Firstly you should upgrade from 2.4.0 to 3.1 and once finished you can follow the documentation to upgrade from 3.1 to 4.1.2